# Null Object reference on room DAO returned object

Tags: java, android, android-room, dao

I am having an issue understanding why i get a null object exception.

My call to the DAO is in onCreate:

```
  AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WDatabase wdatabase = WDatabase.getInstance(MyApplication.getAppContext());
                NDao nDao = wDatabase.nDao();
                MNode mNode = new MNode();
                mNode = nDao.getMNodeByID(516);
                Log.d("NTest", "nData: "+mNode.getNID());
            }
        });
```

The method in my DAO is

```
//Get by id
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MNode WHERE nodeID= :nodeID")
    MNode getMNodeByID(int nodeID);
```

In my Model the variable is, int nodeID

What am i doing wrong to return a null pointer? The Database exists, the node exists in the database? But yet i still get the null object?

Comment: Can you print error log. Check if "nDao" data access object is null.Check if you are able to access dao inside asyncTask

Comment: No I'm not using spring

Comment: nDao prints, it is not null

Comment: It is now Working, I don't seem to have changed anything other that the Dao to return an int and then changed it back to return my MNode again? I will have a check through and see what has changed and post the answer. Thanks for all your help

Comment: post your stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the query like this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM MNode WHERE nodeID= :nodeID")
int getMNodeByID(int nodeID);
```

and it will return the id of your required query

Comment: Thanks for your help, I thought the getting MNode method would need to return an MNode? How do i use a returned int?

Comment: Can I see your code how you use getNodeByID method in your code